# ExcludeProperties on grandchild collection with MVC UpdateModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model A with a collection of Bs with a collection of Cs. When using MVCs built in controller feature UpdateModel i can bind incoming data to my model easily, and also exclude properties not to be bound. Excellent? No!

Suppose I have the following models, I want to exclude the collection of my child collection, but I cannot get that to work so please point me to the right direction

```
class A {
 int Id { get;set;}
 List<B> Bs { get;set;}
}

class B {
 int Id { get;set;}
 List<C> Cs { get;set;}
}

class C {
 int Id { get;set;}
 List<B> Bs { get;set;}
}
```

I've tried the following with no result, meaning the grand child collection is still being updated against my better judgement

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id) {
   A a = GetAById(Id);
   UpdateModel(a, null, null, new { "Bs.Cs" });
   /* Here comes few more lines saving to database etc */
}
```

**UPDATE**
Added the reason why I dont want to update Cs, and that is because it is a many to many relations and that does not play well with UpdateModel, because it is creating new Cs in the database instead on using the "real" ones.

Comment: What is `AViewModel`? Why are you calling `UpdateModel` (if `a` is in `InputModel` then its already updated! Why are you rendering controls for `Cs` if you don't want them?

Comment: AViewModel could as well be just int Id, because I need to get the Id of the post so i know what entity to update? GetAById is calling a repository, returning a entity framework with changetracking.

I want them, the problem in this scenario is that Cs needs to be rendered on the page but not updated, because it is a many to many relations, and UpdateModel does not handle those very kindly :), I'll update my code a bit to make it clearer

Comment: I don't think that would even compile - should't it be `.. new[] { "B.Cs" }`? Your model does not contain a property named `B` so it would need to be `UpdateModel(a, null, null, new[] { "Bs.Cs" });`

Comment: I've updated the code, but it still does not work. It does not exclude the Cs from the binding.

Comment: I've not (and never would) use `UpdateModel` so not sure, but why not just post back the model then update the properties of `a` that you want. And why create controls and post back the values of `C's` if you dont need them anyway?

Comment: Why not use UpdateModel? I find it very easy to use. I need to present Cs on my page, therefor I have a ViewModel containing Cs. What i can do is to create a new ViewModel of B where C is not included, but that will mean alot of extra work if new properties need to be added/removed etc

Comment: You can still 'present' them using `DisplayFor()`, but you don't need to create inputs that post back (why degrade performance by posting a whole lot of stuff you dont need?)